# TypeScript: "Overload signatures must all be ambient or non-ambient" when overloading a function

Tags: typescript, overloading, function-declaration

I am trying to create an overloaded function `getDefaultPath` so that it can **only** accept certain type combinations.

I tried using function signature declarations but it results in a confusing error message for both function declarations:

> Overload signatures must all be ambient or non-ambient.

```js
// type declartions
export enum TABS {
  TAB_A,
  TAB_B
}

export interface TabAParams {
   ...
}

export interface TabBParams {
   ...
}

// Overload signatures
export declare function getDefaultPath(tab: TABS.TAB_A, pathParams: TabAParams): string;
export declare function getDefaultPath(tab: TABS.TAB_B, pathParams: TabBParams): string;

// this function is to be overloaded
export function getDefaultPath(
  tab,
  pathParams
) {
  switch (tab) {
    case TABS.TAB_A:
      return getTabAPath(pathParams); // only accepts TabAParams
    case TABS.TAB_B:
      return getTabBPath(pathParams); // only accepts TabBParams
    default:
      throw new UnreachableCaseError(tab);
  }
}

// helps to avoid missing cases
export default class UnreachableCaseError extends Error {
  constructor(val: never) {
    super(`Unreachable case: ${val}`);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

just remove the `declare` word from overloads and the error is gone.

also take into account that the actual implementation is not checked for types properly and couldn't be changed to be checked, in a way you are trying to implement it, considering what TS have at the moment. Just the usage of this function will be checked properly

Answer (score 1):

There is another way without explicitly using overloading. The arguments to a function in js/ts are just an array. TS allows you to specify the types of individual elements in an array. So the following is possible:

```
type GetDefaultPathParams = (
  [TABS.TAB_A, TabAParams] |
  [TABS.TAB_B, TabBParams]
);

export function getDefaultPath(...params: GetDefaultPathParams)
{
  const tab = params[0];
  const pathParams = params[1];

  switch (tab) {
    case TABS.TAB_A:
      return getTabAPath(pathParams); // only accepts TabAParams
    case TABS.TAB_B:
      return getTabBPath(pathParams); // only accepts TabBParams
    default:
      throw new UnreachableCaseError(tab);
  }
}
```

Comment: Great alternative to overloading! Must easier to read as well imo